# Why is my Script in Google Earth Engine telling me that my training data set function is not a function?

Tags: function, error-handling

I am working on a script in Google Earth Engine Code Editor and this section of my code me an error:

```
var trainingdata = Anthropogenic.merge(Trees).merge(Grass).merge(Shade).merge(Water)

//Create training dataset
var bands = ["B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "ndvi","ndwi"];
  var samples = landsat.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingdata,
  properties: ['ID'],
  scale: 30
});

print(samples)
```

The error code says:

`var samples = landsat.select(bands).sampleRegions({ is not a function`

However, this function has worked for me in a previous script.
Any ideas on how to fix this?